# How do I implement Sweet Alert by RealRashid to confirm Record Delete in controller destroy() method?

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

```
public function destroy(Company $company)
{
    Alert::question('Delete Record?', 'Cannot Undo! Are You Sure?');

    if (session('status')) {
        $company->delete();
    }
    return back()->with('status', 'Company Deleted!');
}
```

At the moment the record deletes with or without the Sweet Alert confirmation. I want the record deleted only after the Sweet Alert confirmation is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Just change button type from submit to button and trigger vai javascript function

```
<form action="{{ route('orders.destroy', $row->id) }}" method="post" class="d-inline">@csrf@method('DELETE')<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger confirm-delete"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button></form>

$(document).on('click', 'button.confirm-delete', function () {
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    $(this).parent('form').trigger('submit')
  } else if (result.isDenied) {
    Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info')
  }
});
```

});

Comment: Ok thank you, but in my case I'm using Sweet Alert by RealRashid which allows you to use sweet alert in your laravel controllers.  From RealRashid documentation, it seems you can use the Sweet alert in your controllers without the need for those Javascript codes. And that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for an answer like you, and I came up with something works perfectly!
If the user is trying to delete something, it will show him warning alert to confirm the delete.. once he clicks on yes it will delete it and show another alert with success of deletion.

Here is how you can do it:

after installing [RealRashid/Sweet-Alert](https://realrashid.github.io/sweet-alert/install) and publish it you need to do this:

In your view:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    //Sweet alert stylesheet
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sweetalert2.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    //refer to rashid's docs
    @include('sweetalert::alert')

    //The delete button
    <a class="btn btn-primary mb-1" href="{{ Route('movies.edit', $movie) }}">
      <i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>
    </a>
    <form action="{{ Route('movies.destroy', $movie) }}" method="post" class="ms-2 mb-1">
      @csrf
      @method('DELETE')

      //The 'confirm' class is important to use in the JavaScript code
      <button class="btn btn-danger confirm" type="submit">
        <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
      </button>
    </form>

    //Add Sweetalert script lib
    <script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        //the confirm class that is being used in the delete button
        $('.confirm').click(function(event) {

            //This will choose the closest form to the button
            var form =  $(this).closest("form");

            //don't let the form submit yet
            event.preventDefault();

            //configure sweetalert alert as you wish
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'هل أنت متأكد؟',
                text: "لا يمكنك التراجع عن حذف الفلم",
                cancelButtonText: "إلغاء",
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'حذف'
            }).then((result) => {
                
                //in case of deletion confirm then make the form submit
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

after doing the above code in your view, head to your controller and do this:

```
//Add use statement for rashid's alert
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;

//in your destroy function you can do this
public function destroy(Movie $movie)
    {
        $movie->genres()->detach();
        $movie->delete();
        return redirect()->route('movies.index')->with('success', 'تم حذف الفلم بنجاح!');
    }

//with success will trigger rashid's alert to pop up and you customize the message in 'with' statement!
```

That's it! you don't need to do anything else or add Alert::success in the controller.. withSuccess works just fine.